# Is there a tool that reports on PKI health (CRL dates, expiry, etc)?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

I'm looking for a tool that will walk the AIA tree from a leaf node and check all corresponding CRL dates and times.

Ideally it will also check versions and cross root trusts.

Does such a tool exist? If not, what is the closest I can get to that goal?

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: @Crypt32 Windows, OSX, but I suppose I can spin up a VM to run this if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to add my one cent.

I'm not aware of any such ready tools, however this feature was requested by a customer of mine some time ago. Eventually, I ended up with my own PowerShell solution for Windows. Here are two blog posts where I describe the behavior:

- [Enterprise PKI (pkiview.msc) PowerShell Edition (PoC)](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/enterprise-pki-pkiviewmsc-powershell-edition-poc.aspx)
- [Enterprise PKI health verifier, PowerShell Edition v1.5](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/enterprise-pki-health-verifier-powershell-edition-v15.aspx)

Although, postings refer to Microsoft ADCS, there is a `-Certificate` parameter where you can pass arbitrary certificate.

Generally, the script does the following:

1. Prepare input certificate;
2. Execute chain for each certificate to select trusted anchors and to go through the chain;
3. Retrieve all Issuer URLs from AIA;
4. Validate each url (must be either http or ldap) and attempt to download the contents;
5. If contents is downloaded, verify whether it is a certificate;
6. Verify if the downloaded certificate is an issuer of the certificate in subject;
7. Validate other cert properties;
8. Extract URLs from CDP extension;
9. Validate each url (must be either http or ldap) and attempt to download the contents;
10. If contents is downloaded, verify whether it is a CRL;
11. Validate basic CRL properties, like validity (not yet valid, expired, about to expire);
12. Validate whether the CRL has valid signature (against CA certificate);
13. Do the same for DeltaCRLs;
14. Extract all OCSP URLs from AIA extension;
15. Validate OCSP response by sending OCSP request and processing response;
16. Compose status report (managed, I maintain report object and you can access report properties);
17. Repeat steps 3-16 for each subsequent certificate in the chain up to root certificate;
18. Compose summary report.

Not all you've requested (cross-certificates are not verified), but enough for a good start.

Where to get the latest version of the script? It is a part of my PowerShell PKI module. Download sources of the most recent release: https://pspki.codeplex.com/releases

you will need only three files:

- `Get-EnterprisePKIHealthStatus.ps1`
- `PKI.Core.dll`
- `SysadminsLV.Asn1Parser.dll`

All files are digitally signed by me. If you concern about dlls, they are opensourced: [PKIX.NET](https://github.com/Crypt32/pkix.net) (PKI.Core.dll) and [Asn1DerParser.NET](https://github.com/Crypt32/Asn1DerParser.NET) (SysadminsLV.Asn1Parser.dll)

and the last, online help for PowerShell function: [Get-EnterprisePKIHealthStatus](https://www.sysadmins.lv/projects/pspki/Get-EnterprisePKIHealthStatus.aspx).

HTH

Comment: "Just to add my one cent"  Don't be so modest, that was a top percentile answer. You provide code you wrote yourself to handle an issue related to usability of crypto, explain the workings in natural language , and provide the code in a verfiably secure manner. I wish i could upvote more.

Comment: Note: "PSPKI" is the PowerShell version of Microsoft's graphical tool [`pkiview.msc`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pki/2011/02/28/quick-check-on-adcs-health-using-enterprise-pki-tool-pkiview/). Which is a bit hidden, but still [exists in Win2010R2.](https://www.petri.com/certificate-authority-health-windows-server-2012-r2-pkiview)

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff it is incorrect. PSPKI is PowerShell module for PKI/ADCS task automation. PowerShell version of Microsoft's PKIView.msc is just a functionality provided by a module. Entire module offers a ton of other features.

Comment: I stand corrected!